# How to check if file is empty in Julia?

Tags: io, julia

Okey, I want to plot some points that are stored in an array text file (the usual tabular text file) in Julia. I can retrieve the values by a simple 
`data=readdlm("FileInCase01.dat")` if the file is not empty. If the file is empty I want `data=[]`, an empty array and an empty plot. The file ALWAYS exists. So `isfile` is of no use. But sometimes it is empty. If I try to use `readdlm` on an empty file it returns an error:

`LoadError: at row 0, column 0 : ArgumentError("number of rows in dims must be > 0, got 0")
while loading In[21], in expression starting on line 2`

Which suggests that readdlm cannot return an empty array. So I have to check beforehand if the file is empty or not. How is that supposed to be done?

Comment: How about using `try` and `catch`? These are supposed to allow users to catch exactly these kind of non-recoverable errors from functions and do something specific to the application (a full blown example can be found in docs or given by request).

Answer (score 7):

You can check file sizes with [`filesize`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.filesize):

```
shell> cat test.csv
#

julia> filesize("test.csv")
2
```

The file size will be `0` for an empty file.  But watch out: even though "test.csv" isn't empty, `readdlm` will still throw an error since it only contains the comment character:

```
julia> readdlm("test.csv")
ERROR: at row 0, column 0 : ArgumentError("number of rows in dims must be > 0, got 0")
```

So @DanGetz's suggestion for a try/catch block is probably the more robust way to handle failures here.